# how to remove products from home page in magento

Tags: magento, product

I have a category contains 9 products
and I'm using this code inside the homepage cms

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" column_count="4" category_id="7"  template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

but that's displays all 9 products on the homepage and 
I want to display only 4 products, How can I choose what products to show in the homepage and what not?

Comment: Debug that template and see if it looks for a custom variable in the products.

Comment: i cant find it .. there is so many list.phtml

Comment: use templates hints to find the directory of the template you're using.

Answer (score 0):

Replace column_count=4 by is_homepage=1

and in the phtml add this :

```
<?php if($this->getIsHomepage() && $i==4) break; ?>
```

before this :

```
<?php if ($i++%$_columnCount==0): ?>
```